# Rails db:create error. Could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided or not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to rerun an old rails project in my local environment. The frontend is working but I'm having errors on creating the database.

$ rails db:create

```
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_HOST") { "localhost" } %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_USERNAME") { "postgres" } %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_PASSWORD") { nil } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_production
```

Comment: Can you provide the Docker commands used to run the containers? It appears to be an issue with your networking between containers (if the database and app are running in separate ones) or how you're setting environment variables. But no one can help troubleshoot without more info.

Comment: How old is this Rails project? Before Rails 5 (iirc) you had to run `rake db:create` - rails cli was "not aware" of the default rake tasks...